# Cannot load anything from library

Tags: library, compile

So I installed libraries through the Arduino interface (`Sketch` > `Include Library` > `Manage Library`). Then I check: `C:\Users\username\OneDrive\Documents\Arduino\Libraries`, and I confirm the new libraries are there.

However, when I compile I always get the error that Arduino cannot find the library, no matter which one I try to import.

I'm on Arduino 1.8.5, Windows. What am I missing?

Comment: Does this answer help? https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/51813/this-error-is-shown-continuosly-after-first-time-it-compiles-successfully/51825#51825

Comment: @VE7JRO OH MY GOD!! It was OneDrive!?? What the what!? Thanks, this solved it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a problem with using your OneDrive folder.

[duskwuff wrote](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/53951/19409):

> [This is a known incompatibility between the Arduino IDE and Microsoft OneDrive](https://github.com/arduino/arduino-builder/issues/254). A fix should be available soon; in the meantime, move your Arduino sketches out of the OneDrive folder.

The issue with OneDrive folders has been resolved as of version 1.8.6.

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ReleaseNotes

> ARDUINO 1.8.6 2018.08.23
>
> [ide]
>
> - Updated arduino-builder to 1.4.0:
>
>   - parallel build (improve compile speed)
>   - better reuse of already compiled files
>   - **Windows: fixed build for sketch stored under OneDrive cloud folders**

Simply update to a newer version of the Arduino IDE and you will be able to compile and upload your sketch.