# Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno

I am getting the following error message when compiling a program on my Arduino IDE. This does not happen when compiling the given example programs in the IDE.

The error message is as follows :

```
Arduino: 1.8.5 (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"

C:\Program Files\Arduino\arduino-builder -dump-prefs -logger=machine -hardware 
C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware -tools 
C:\Program Files\Arduino\tools-builder -tools
C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -built-in-libraries 
C:\Program Files\Arduino\libraries -libraries 
C:\Users\mahim\OneDrive\Documents\Arduino\libraries -fqbn=arduino:avr:uno -ide-version=10805 -build-path 
C:\Users\mahim\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_361527 -warnings=none -build-cache 
C:\Users\mahim\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_cache_227236 -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA.path=
C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc.path=
C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude.path=
C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr -verbose 
C:\Users\mahim\OneDrive\Documents\Arduino\3potpass\3potpass.ino
readlink 
C:\Users\mahim\OneDrive\Documents\Arduino\3potpass\3potpass.ino: The system cannot find the file specified.

Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino Uno.
```

Answer (score 2):

[This is a known incompatibility between the Arduino IDE and Microsoft OneDrive](https://github.com/arduino/arduino-builder/issues/254). A fix should be available soon; in the meantime, move your Arduino sketches out of the OneDrive folder.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from [duskwuff's answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/53951/19409), the issue with OneDrive folders has been resolved as of version 1.8.6.

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ReleaseNotes

> ARDUINO 1.8.6 2018.08.23
>
> [ide]
>
> - Updated arduino-builder to 1.4.0:
>
>   - parallel build (improve compile speed)
>   - better reuse of already compiled files
>   - **Windows: fixed build for sketch stored under OneDrive cloud folders**

Simply update to a newer version of the Arduino IDE and you will be able to compile and upload your sketch.